# Range values SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, range

I have a column with values from '10000023' TO '50000000', i need to create a second column filling in for every row from 10000023 to 10000023+500 and go on.

Eg.

```
Pos       |   Interval_pos

10000023     100000523
10000523     100001023
 ...            ...
49999500     50000000
```

is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `generate_series()`:

```
select pos, pos + 500
from (select generate_series(minpos, maxpos - 500, 500) as pos
      from (select min(pos) as minpos, max(pos) as maxpost
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
ALTER TABLE _table add column interval_pos integer;

update _table set interval_pos = (pos + 500);
```